# Retrieving parameter of a function using regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

for example if we consider document.createElement() function the parameter can be passed in 3 ways

`var v="script";
 var s=document.createElement(v);`

`var s=document.createElement("script");`

`var s=document.createElement('scipt');`

i want a regular expression which extracts the parameter in document.createElement function excluding quotes. I tried this by using groups but i am writing two regular expression one for "",'' and other for normal variable
please provide an example

Comment: You're going to parse JavaScript code with regexes?! Better wrap `document.createElement` to make hook. Also, script may be inserted via `document.body.innerHTML += "<script type='text/javascript'></script>"`.

Comment: what does that mean wrapping document.createElement? please explain

Comment: `var f = document.createElement; document.createElement = function(tagName){ console.log(tagName); f.apply(document, arguments); }` This code is tracking `document.createElement` calls dynamically, though. I.e. One cannot say about some code which tags are created beforehead.

Comment: thank you so much can you provide any tutorial which clearly explains this concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var re = /document\.createElement\((['"]*)(.+?)\1\)/;
```

The result is in:

```
str.match(re)[2];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/RWc8N/

Comment: This does not match var s=document.createElement(v);

Comment: it is not working because in the above code v is not in double quotes or single quotes.

Comment: did you check the example? I have return the correct result for all 3 cases...I'm not sure what you mean in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Use pipe - `|` for *OR* operations.

For example: `script|scipt`.